# SSH inside SSH heredoc

Tags: bash, ssh, heredoc

I'm writing a script that logs into a remote server via SSH and executes some commands, one of which logs into a second remote server (which I can't access locally) via SSH and executes a command. After that nested SSH command, my original SSH command terminates and does't complete the rest of the heredoc. I've simplified the script a bit, but I get the same results:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh server1 <<'EOF'
  echo one $HOSTNAME
  ssh server2 'echo two $HOSTNAME'    
  echo three $HOSTNAME
EOF
```

my output looks like this:

```
one server1
two server2
```

I would expect to see `three server1` at the end of my output, but it doesn't happen. I'm able to separate these into two SSH commands and get what I need, but I'm curious why this is happening, and is it possible to get what I expect in one shot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
ssh server2
```

with

```
ssh -n server2
```

to prevent ssh reading from stdin.

Comment: That works. I see in the ssh manpage that `-n` redirects stdin from /dev/null, but I'm not sure how that relates to the commands that follow.

Comment: I'm trying to explain. `ssh server2` gets two commands in your example. The first command is `echo two $HOSTNAME` and the second (`echo three $HOSTNAME`) via stdin. The second is ignored. If you remove first command, ssh executes your second command from stdin (replace `ssh server2 'echo two $HOSTNAME'` with `ssh server2`).